# jQuery error Unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I have some code working perfectly on a specific source solution which references jQuery 1.7.2

Now I copy/paste this source code to another solution which references jQuery 1.8.0

I don't know if jQuery version is the origin of my problem but I got an error: **Unrecognized expression**

Here is the source code:

```
$('#ScreenshotsTable tr.#' + screenshotID).remove();
```

Where screenshotID is (for example) equal to 7.

So as you can see, I would like to remove a line from a table.

Any idea why I got the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `.` from your selector:

```
$('#ScreenshotsTable tr#' + screenshotID).remove();
```

IDs are unique, you can code:

```
$('#'+screenshotID).remove();
```

<sub>Please note that if the doctype of the page is not HTML5, IDs must begin with a letter.</sub>

Comment: You are right. But why do this code worked with jQuery 1.7.2 and not with 1.8.0 ? Thanks anyway?

Comment: @Bronzato I'm not sure that your code works with 1.7.2 version, as your are combining the `class` and `id` selectors.